# to pass variable from one swf to another swf in as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a main swf in as3 and I load another swf in as3 in it. Now I want the main swf to pass variable to loaded swf. Which is not happening ? pls. help!

Regards,
Sagar

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by

[Passing parameters to a loaded SWF application](http://flexdevtips.blogspot.com/2009/02/passing-parameters-to-loaded-swf.html)

by changing the load parameters and using `application.loaderInfo` to get the variable.

```
loader.load("SWFLoaderApp.swf?test=hi");
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [LocalConnection](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/LocalConnection.html) class. :-)

-EDIT-

Apologies. I misread your question. I didn't read that the first swf would load in the second swf.